# How can I filter blog posts by author?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'll use have_posts function to fetch messages, how can I filter posts by author name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write your own query to include or exclude posts from an Author
This page has documentation about the different options you can pass to a query. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts

Here is an example to only get posts from the user 'wade'

```
$author_query = new WP_Query('author_name=wade');
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few plug-ins which can do this for you - such [as this one](http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/posts-by-author-plugin-for-wordpress/)

If they don't quite what you want, they should serve as a good starting point for writing your own plugin (which isn't that scary or difficult)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to just skip posts in the loop that belong to a certain author. Like so:

```
<?php if (get_post_author($post) == "wade") continue; ?>
```

This would be useful if you are using multiple loops in a page and want to filter out certain users' posts without creating multiple `WP_Query`s.

Answer (score 1):

just append ?author=4 to the url

with the 4 being the author ID