# How can I get Wordpress archives by author username?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get archives of one author and exlude all others, Wordpress wp get archives() doesn't have that kind of filter. How can I fitler all other others except one author from archives?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_get_archives

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just off the top of my head:

```
get_posts(array('author_name' => 'the_authors_name'))
```

You don't get anything preformatted like from `wp_get_archives`, just the list of posts, but you get the posts by author. If you need to do more fancy things or want to run a WP Loop you can do a custom `WP_Query` object as well.

Comment: It appears this has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333701/how-can-i-filter-blog-posts-by-author